# Including all /javascript/*.js from a directory

Tags: php, javascript, include

Can anyone tell me the best practice for including a set of files in a directory?

For instance, if I had a directory that was /javascript, and in there it had 10 javascript files, how would I go about loading the entire directory?

This question is moot now, but for future reference;

I use the following to read files in the ***same manner***:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Auto import all js files in the directory.

            $files = glob("*.js");
            sort($files);                   

            $jsFiles = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
                error_log('Auto-Opening: '.$files[$i]);
                $tempString = file_get_contents($files[$i]);
                //error_log('Auto-Opened Content: '.$tempString);
                array_push($jsFiles, $tempString);
            }
?>
```

Sorry, I guess this needs clarification:

The code I have included is used in an entirely seperate part of my project, it includes the RAW string format of a directory of javascript files for my processing purposes. You do not have to worry about why I am doing this.

I *could* use this to add `script` tags, and echo these files, but I am looking for a faster more elegant way to include a directory. Unlike the code above (whose javascript never gets executed by my code. I simply create the string from the files and send it to JS for parsing).

Please also note, as suggested:

```
$files = glob("{directory/*.js}",GLOB_BRACE);
                for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
                    include($files[$i]);
                }
```

Does nothing but echo those files to the screen, without `script` tags.

Comment: Is there a reason you 're reading the contents instead of outputting `<script src="...">` tags?

Comment: I imagine it's concatenation; serving one file instead on ten.

Comment: If you wanna make a include for example to use some functions inside a file -> create a single_file.php and call everything inside this, with <script src="dir/file.js"> then make a call of single_file.php in your scripts, then all js files will be present there, and you can use functions from that file...

Comment: Maybe he wants to reduce the number of http request :)

Comment: Yeah, so neither of those three things. I am reading the directory as strings because I am doing some parsing with the raw JS (but that is separate from what I am doing here). I know to use php to include a bunch of files by statically coding them in, I want to do it on a by directory basis that is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could use this to add script tags, and echo these files, but I am
>   looking for a faster more elegant way to include a directory. Unlike
>   the code above (whose javascript never gets executed by my code. I
>   simply create the string from the files and send it to JS for
>   parsing).

If you want the output of the PHP script to get executed as javascript, you need to add a proper header:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
foreach (glob('/path/to/files/*.js') as $file)
{
    readfile($file);
}
```

> I am reading the directory as strings because I am doing some parsing
>   with the raw JS (but that is separate from what I am doing here). I
>   know to use php to include a bunch of files by statically coding them
>   in, I want to do it on a by directory basis that is dynamic.

Unless you have some sort of file naming convention going on, remember that the order of the files is going to be basically limited to what you can do with php's array sorting functions on the file names. JS and CSS are often very dependent on code or files being executed or read in a certain order, so depending on what it is you're actually trying to accomplish (still very unclear), this might be an awful idea.

Comment: No sorry, I *have* output buffering already, I am looking for the opposite. I want the php file to print and execute the javascript.

Comment: Ok, then remove the `ob_*` functions from the example, and then what is the matter? Oh wait, I think I get it - see edit.

Comment: I think you may be right here. I'll see if adding the header works. I understand your concern for the order of execution, and this is valid. However its the vary nature of the directories that allow me to do this, because each directory only contains classes that are on the same 'level', and thus can be executed in any order.

Comment: The header will work only *if* you are referencing the php script as a javascript file, i.e. `<script src="/js/dir/my-script.php"></script>`. It's still *really unclear* what you're trying to do, where and how you are running the script, and what you are doing with the output. I don't care what you do with it, but when asking vague questions, you can't just assume everyone else knows what you're after. You have to understand that your idea is very unorthodox for a lot of good reasons.

Comment: What do you mean??!! How can I be any more clear? I have a directory: lets call it A. Directory A is filled with 10 javascript files, lets say: A.js, B.js, C.js etc,. I would like all of those files to *dynamically* be loaded/executed from php simply because they live in directory A. This is to say, a loop that loads all files that match the path: 'A/*.js'.

Comment: What you are doing with the output was the mystery. "Loading" a javascript file could mean a few different things, and you seemed to imply that you wanted to parse the output before printing it (like with jsmin or something), and nowhere did you mention if the php script output was within a `<script>` tag or if it the php file was referenced with the `src` attribute (there's a big difference).

Comment: I believe it is your *bias* from reading the question that is making you *assume* that I'm trying to do something I'm not. If you didn't assume my question was wrong, you would understand how to answer it. I am doing both. I load the files *twice*. Once to include as standard javascript as any other website would (which my question is about), and one for entirely separate purposes that does not need to be explained here as I previously stated *several times*. Its your assumption that you believe I'm doing something that I shouldn't be that is frustrating for me.

Comment: I *did not* ask you to discuss with me *why* I am doing what I am doing, simply how to do it, and that was for a reason: to avoid the discussion we are currently having. Thank you for your help, I am very grateful for your response.

Comment: To be clear: I didn't care *why*, but I needed to know *how* in order to answer the question. If you `include` the file that runs the glob with php into your HTML, that's one answer. If you reference the file it with a script tag, that's another answer. You didn't specify. No need to freak out at the people trying to help you, by yelling in your post for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply call `include()` on the files rather than doing a `file_get_contents()`. This is for two main reasons/benefits:

- You are not loading the files into memory (in PHP anyway) before outputing them. This saves server resources (albeit a fairly small amount).
- You can put PHP code into your JS/CSS etc and have it be evaluated. This means you can predefine JS variables at the server side, apply colour themes to your CSS and a multitude of other things very simply through PHP.

Comment: Are you saying if I loop through $files and call include($files[i]), it should work as I expect?

Comment: `readfile()` I believe is faster than `file_get_contents()` and won't execute PHP like `include` will (if for some reason, there is any).

Comment: Yes, just like HTML templating. It's all just plain text at the end of the day... It might be worth outputting a CRLF in between the includes, so you don't break anything from a file that doesn't a trailing new line.

Comment: @Wesley makes a good point - if you didn't want to evaluate any PHP code inside the files, `readfile()` would be better/faster. The difference is marginal but it all adds up...

Comment: fyi, include is the equivalent to: `eval('?> . file_get_contents('file.php') . '<?php;');` and can be upto 20% slower.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will not output `<script>` tags for you. It has no idea what JS is, other than a chunk of text. Your glob version is close, but would have to be:

```
$files = glob("{directory/*.js}",GLOB_BRACE);
for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    include($files[$i]);
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Compile your Javascript files into a single, minified source using the [Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), and have your HTML reference that instead.

Comment: @nephi12: Oops! Sorry. I think you wrote to me by mistake, or I misread it. And now I've got the whole thing deleted. Dammit...

Comment: i was just saying that you were right and that the OP should have apologized to you, and that they were acting like a child. i should have said "to the OP....." but i didnt. sorry.

Comment: @nephi12: Thanks for sticking up for me. :-) You were right, and I feel silly now.

Comment: [Yay](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150634/all-comments-on-this-post) for Stack Exchange Data Explorer! [Comments immortalised](http://pastebin.com/hpJseNTt)

Comment: wowza. 1. I had no clue that existed... 2. umm... does that mean... bye!